# Does home security system only link to wire-powered smoke detector but not the battery-powered ones?

Tags: electrical, security, smoke-detectors, carbon-monoxide

Currently my home has battery-powered smoke/CO detectors, I wonder if in the future I am setting up a home monitoring security system with commercial company for the whole house (to detect things like abnormal temperature, burglar, smoke, fire, and carbon monoxide, etc), will it only be connected to smoke/CO detectors that are powered via wiring behind the walls, and not compatible with battery-powered smoke/CO detectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system will only be compatible with smoke/fire/CO detectors that are designed to communicate with your new system. The communication connectivity is traditionally accomplished with wires; however, there are now integrated systems that provide interconnectivity between *specific devices* that use wireless (RF) technology.

Either way, if you want detectors that connect and report, rather than function as "stand alone" alarms, you will need to replace them.

Answer (score 3):

In short: yes that’s correct.

However there are wireless alarm systems, but they’ll use different battery smokes than you currently have.

Comment: sorry I basically duplicated your answer. Didn't see it till I hit the button and the screen refreshed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. The home security system linked smoke detector has relay output contact to trigger alarm and it requires 12V or at least 5v power supply. Battery power is not enough.